# How to hide the border radius of a parent that has overflow set to scroll?

Tags: html, css

The parent has `border-radius` of `5px`. The children (the top black part) has `border-radius` of `3px`. This made the parent's border to be covered by the children's

However, I needed to enable th user to scroll the content of the parent, but to do that I had to set the parent to `overflow: scroll`

But this made the parent's border to show up again (the white on the top left):

[image: I]

How can I enable scrolling and hid the parent's border radius at the same time?

Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qjog7tvu/

Answer (score 1):

Set `border-radius` of child to `5px` initially and when it user starts scrolling after scrolling till the header change border-radius to 3px with jquery like this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   var headerHeight = $('header').height()
   $('article[_v-e514def2]').scrollTop(headerHeight);
   $('header').css('border-radius','3px');
})
```

According to my knowledge this is the only solution as if there is `5px` border-radius of parent and `3px` of child then it is natural that 2px space will be there so the best you can do is change it dynamically.